# Submitting data from several userforms to specified worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

When I was working with only one userform this code worked well.

```
Private Sub CommandButtonSubmitSalesEntry_Click()

Dim nextrow As String
'find next empty row

nextrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("a:a")) + 1    
Cells(nextrow, 1) = TextBoxDate.Text    
Cells(nextrow, 2) = EmployeeNames.Text    
Cells(nextrow, 3) = ComboBoxStationNames.Text    
Cells(nextrow, 4) = ComboBoxSalesRates.Text  

Unload Me
UserFormSales.Show
```

Now that I have created a second Userform they have begun submitting data to random worksheets.  How do I define which worksheet I want the data to go to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply activate the Sheet you want:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
```

Comment: Thanks. That was way too easy... One of many Rookie mistakes to come.